# Equivalent of "JOIN EACH" for a subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query with a large subquery, and am getting the following error: Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins.

So, is there an equivalent of JOIN EACH for sub queries, where I can join larger tables  than 8mb?  I didn't see anything in the docs or when I searched around.  Here is the query I am using-- if there is a way to rewrite this to fit better with the bigquery model then I am also open to that.

```
SELECT *
FROM [x.y]
WHERE column_hash NOT IN (
SELECT column_hash from [x.z]
)
```

Comment: Why can't you put "JOIN EACH" in your query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you're performing is doing an anti-join, not a subquery.  You can re-write this as an explicit join, but it is a little verbose:

```
SELECT y.* -- Note you may have to expand out these fields yourself
FROM [x.z] as z
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [x.y] as y ON y.column_hash = z.column_hash
WHERE y.column_hash is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan!  In my case the actual query was "SELECT y.* FROM [x.y] as y LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [x.z] as z ON y.column_hash = z.column_hash WHERE z.column_hash IS NULL", which has the same form of the query you provided, but is reversed.  I need to brush up on my SQL...